# Use of "to can" meaning be capable of doing something

Tags: word-in-context

Can the verb “to can” be used when saying that someone is capable of doing something bad or reprehensible like in the sentences below:

> I know we are talking about kidnapping and murder, but you must agree
>   that these are things a man like him can do.
>
> When it comes to conquering power everybody knows the things politicians
>   can do.

Also, these sentences being correct, should the word "that" be used before the subject (**...things that a man like him can do / ...things that politicians can do**) or is it not necessary?

Comment: "That" is two questions. An answer to the main one is yes, something they are capable of, not in the sense of physical ability (most adults might be strong enough) but emotionally, in their character, their nature.

Comment: Please note: there is no verb "to can" except to mean put something in a can. However, there **would** is better for the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me with this question. I'll post another oner later about the use of "that". 

Lambie, where you wrote "there would" did you mean "these would be", Sorry but I'm not sure I understood your explanation.

Thanks again.

Comment: there=at that place :)